# How to remove CDATA from my xml parser?

Tags: android, xml-parsing

Hi i need to remove the CDATA from the xml which i need to parse . I parse all the values but the cdata is not getting. please help me on this

Comment: the cdata is not getting what?

Comment: want to get contents inside the cdata <![CDATA[ Fonction publique
  ]]>

Comment: It should "just work". You'll need to show us some code before we could suggest why it isn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally the parser ignores CDATA by definition, but in android you can get it by using the nexttoken function to find it and then gettext to retrieve the text inside of it.

You can read about it on this page:
http://developer.android.com/reference/org/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParser.html